# AG-Grid: Is there a way to receive a callback when a custom Tool Panel renders?

Tags: ag-grid

I've created a [custom Tool Panel component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-tool-panel/) in ag-grid, and I need to know when it renders to the DOM so I can work with these DOM elements.

I'm actually trying to put another ag-grid inside the panel, and waiting for it to render so I can call `new agGrid.Grid()`

I'm having trouble finding a clean method of doing this that doesn't feel hacky, any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toolPanelVisibleChanged` event for this as follows:

```
onToolPanelVisibleChanged: (params) => {
  if (params.source === <panel ID here>) {
     // ... code here
  }
},
```

Working example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/vWYKcbKXfofEhrWn

If you need the code to run just once, when the component is loaded, add whatever code you need to the `init` method of your component:

Example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/DLyh6HpIRJn8diSS

Comment: Thanks, I'd played around with onToolPanelVisibleChanged, I only want it to trigger on initial render so I'd have to keep track of this in a variable, for example: https://plnkr.co/edit/B023m6G8Txl9tRuh there's a downside however, if this Tool Panel isn't the default it doesn't render until the user clicks it. In my case I would of preferred the rendering to start before the user clicks the sidebar so the content was loaded and rendered when the user clicks.

Comment: I do have a very hacky solution https://plnkr.co/edit/6ORvnsCPB4tOlbkQ in CustomStatsToolPanel I add the html `<img src onerror="alert('hacky')">` because there's no "src" provided it calls onerror.  This actually works perfectly even though it makes me feel dirty.

I just wish there was something more elegant. I've considered watching the DOM and waiting for the content to be added but it seems like over kill.

Comment: @SeanBannister I added more code to the example above showing how to run code just when your component loads. Hope it helps.

Comment: @GuihermeLopes thanks, the problem with putting code in Init() is it gets called before getGui() whereas my need is to know when getGui() completes, after the DOM is rendered, so I can interact with DOM. Hence my hacky solution.